# How to prove a function has no local minima.?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have a function  $ f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, of class $C^2$ that satisfies:

$3\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)+4\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}(x,y)=-1$, for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

How to prove that such $f$ can't have local minima. Is an indirect proof easier?

Comment: What does class $C^2$ mean?

Comment: It means $f$ is continuously differentiable two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At  points $(x,y)$ where $\nabla f(x,y)\ne{\bf 0}$ we cannot have a local minimum. Consider now a point ${\bf p}:=(x_0,y_0)$ with $\nabla f({\bf p})={\bf 0}$.

Since $3f_{xx}({\bf p})+4f_{yy}({\bf p})<0$ by assumption, at least one of $f_{xx}({\bf p})$, $f_{yy}({\bf p})$ is negative. Assume that $c:=f_{xx}({\bf p})<0$ and consider the auxiliary function
$$\phi(t):=f(x_0+t,y_0)\qquad(-h<t<h)\ .$$
Then by Taylor's theorem we have
$$\phi(t)=\phi(0)+\phi'(0)t+{c\over2}t^2+o(t^2)\qquad(t\to0)\ .$$
Since $\phi'(0)=f_x({\bf p})=0$ this implies
$$f(x_0+t,y_0)=f(x_0,y_0)+\left({c\over2}+o(1)\right)t^2\qquad(t\to0)\ ,$$
from which we conclude that $f(x_0+t,y_0)<f(x_0,y_0)$ for all small enough $|t|\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}<0$
or
$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}<0$

what does it tell you? with regards to condition of minimum

if you want more explanation as follows

$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} <0$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} >0$ then $D<0$

$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}>0$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}<0$ again $D<0$

if both are negative then its local maxima

hope that helps

Comment: So if one can't conclude the determinant of the Hessian is defined positive, is that sufficient as a contradiction?

Comment: of course since its saddle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point                   saddle implies its not an extremum